# How to get value of checked radio?

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div id="chips">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet_chipped" class="chipped" value="Yes" id="chipyes" checked> Yes</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet_chipped" class="chipped" value="No" id="chipno"> No</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("input[name='pet_chipped']:checked").val();
```

when I am alerting 'pet_chipped' it displaying undefined.

Comment: It should work. Can you create a snippet?

Comment: it displaying undefined

Comment: Is your script tag before the HTML, e.g. in the `<head>`? You need to move it until after the `<div id="chips">` so that the elements exist at the time the code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//onload event
$(document).ready(function(){
  /*show alert on load time*/
  alert($('[name="pet_chipped"]:checked').val());
})
// on change radio button value fire event 
$(document).on('change', '[name="pet_chipped"]', function(){
  //show value of radio after changed
   alert($('[name="pet_chipped"]:checked').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chips">
<label> <input type="radio" name="pet_chipped" class="chipped" value="Yes" id="chipyes" checked> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pet_chipped" class="chipped" value="No" id="chipno"> No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Satpal that can be identified once OP's question putted into a fiddle. And currently edit queue is full. And you can place into fiddle. So that it can become easy to identify OP's mistake (if any).

Comment: Can you please open link http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Found and check why it displaying undefined.

Comment: when I am submitting it alerting undefined. only one alert of undefined.

Comment: Thanks for replay @RushabhShah, can u plz provide me ur js link.

Comment: and in ur code i get this -> var pet_chipped = $("#pet_chipped").val();
so its not right.
var pet_chipped = $("[name="pet_chipped"]:checked).val();

Comment: I wrote in the footer you checked error? why it displaying undefined?

Comment: Ok good @RushabhShah
And upvote my question so it help someone in feature

Comment: @SureshSuthar If you want your answer to *"help someone in [the future]"*, please consider adding an explanation to your code snippet and correcting the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="pet_chipped" class="chipped" value="Yes">    Yes</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="pet_chipped" class="chipped" value="No" checked> No</label>
<input type="submit" onclick="getChecked()" />
```

Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getChecked(){
var checked = $("input[name='pet_chipped']:checked").val();
alert(checked);
}
</script>
```